# htaccess - overwrite root htaccess with subdirectory htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My php files are located at  "htdocs **/app/public/** " that I need to show on root of the website and wordpress is at "htdocs **/wp/** "

Previously I used code below to "htdocs **/app/public/** " requests as "htdocs/"

```
 #laravel htaccess    - location : /htdocs/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to have access on wordpress at "htdocs **/wp/** ", so I added code below.

```
 # WordPress - htaccess below laravel htaccess code   
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /wp/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    </IfModule>
```

Is that possible to overwrite root htaccess on **wp** directory?

Comment: If `wp/.htaccess` is there then anything starting with `http://example.com/wp/` will not be affected by root .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava thanks, I found wp/.htaccess had "RewriteOptions inherit", so I removed it